# how to set a static ip address for a server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, samba, vpn

I have file server that uses Samba. I connect to it through VPN and SSH. Sometimes, the server's IP address changes, and I can't access my files or SSH into it. I want to set a fixed IP address, but I can't locate the '/etc/network/interfaces' file. I'm not sure if the configuration is in 'netplan' or 'resolv.conf,' and I'm worried about making a mistake. Can someone guide me through the process step by step?
I have ubuntu server 23.04

Comment: Hi there - you should be able to google static ip address ubuntu 23.04 and find some suggestions. You're looking for a file in  /etc/netplan/ probably.

Comment: You should be looking into documentation about Netplan.  However, you can't get a static IP address just because you want one -- it depends on what you're connected to.  For example, if you're at home with a router, then you can probably force an IP address based on the MAC address (there will be a setting in the router for that).  If you're at work and your network is managed by an IT department, most likely they won't allow you a static IP without prior permission...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.